# How to import recursive-readdir in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am a little bit struggling with import and usage of npm module [recursive-readdir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recursive-readdir) in a typescript program.

After `npm install recursive-readdir @types/recursive-readdir` (@types/recursive-readdir@2.2.0, recursive-readdir@2.2.2) the following snippet works:

```js
import * as RecursiveReaddir from 'recursive-readdir';

async function test () {
    const files = await RecursiveReaddir.default('/tmp');
    ...
}
```

The file `node_modules/@types/recursive-readdir/index.d.ts` contains:

```js
...
import * as fs from "fs";
declare namespace RecursiveReaddir {
    type IgnoreFunction = (file: string, stats: fs.Stats) => boolean;
    type Ignores = ReadonlyArray<string|IgnoreFunction>;
    type Callback = (error: Error, files: string[]) => void;
    interface readDir {
        (path: string, ignores?: Ignores): Promise<string[]>;
        (path: string, callback: Callback): void;
        (path: string, ignores: Ignores, callback: Callback): void;
    }
}

declare var recursiveReadDir: RecursiveReaddir.readDir;
export = recursiveReadDir;
```

My questions:

1. Where is the function `RecursiveReaddir.default(...)` coming from?
2. Is there a more readable and intuitive import and usage possible?
   In example `ìmport { readDir } from 'recursive-readdir';` or something like that?

Testprogram is available under:
https://github.com/ManfredSteiner/stackovf_65391266

Answer (score 3):

I got the error in your code.
`(node:7541) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: RecursiveReaddir.default is not a function`

So, I implemented it to work by referring to the existing test codes. See below

- [npm/recursive-readdir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recursive-readdir)
- [github/recursive-readdir](https://github.com/jergason/recursive-readdir#readme)

#### test.ts

```js
// ./test.ts
import recursive from 'recursive-readdir';

async function test () {
    const files = await recursive(__dirname);
    console.log(files);
}

test()
```

#### commands

```sh
# node v12.13.1
# npm v6.11.3
npm install @types/recursive-readdir && \
npm install recursive-readdir

+ @types/recursive-readdir@2.2.0
+ recursive-readdir@2.2.2

tsc && node ./build/test.js
```

#### results

```sh
# Success
[ '/Users/kmk/Project/src/github.com/myeongkil/tmp/stackoverflow/recursive-readdir/build/test.js' ]
```

Comment: I try again the snippet from scratch. `RecursiveReaddir.default()` is transpiled and working, but I replace `__dirname` by `/tmp`. I also see that your "solution" `import recursive from 'recursive-readdir';` is working. But why? I cannot see `recursive` in file `index.d.ts`. Both solutions stay strange for me.

Comment: I add a testprogram repository, see [https://github.com/ManfredSteiner/stackovf_65391266](https://github.com/ManfredSteiner/stackovf_65391266)